# OR in left join

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, left-join

billboards table 140000 rows, regions 1000 rows.

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    SUM(IF(bb.r1_id = r.id, 1, 0)) AS count,
    SUM(IF(bb.r2_id = r.id, 1, 0)) AS count2
FROM
    tmp_regions AS r
LEFT JOIN
    tmp_billboards AS bb
    ON (r.id = bb.r1_id OR r.id = bb.r2_id) 
WHERE
    bb.deleted = 0 
    AND
    bb.x != 0 
    AND
    bb.y != 0
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY r.capital DESC , r.other , r.name
```

execution time is 8 sec

Explain

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  bb  ref bb_r,bb_deleted,bb_x,bb_y,deleted_x_y,bb_r2 bb_deleted  1   const   66396   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  r   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    1000    Using where; Using join buffer
```

how can i change OR in join to improve perfomance?

Comment: First, change the `LEFT` join to inner join.

Comment: i did: execution time ~ 6.8 - 7 secs. Same explain output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `tmp_regions (id)` is the primary key, you could rewrite the query and the `OR` is converted to 2 joins:

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    COALESCE(bb1.cnt, 0) AS count,
    COALESCE(bb2.cnt, 0) AS count2
FROM
    tmp_regions AS r
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT r1_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM tmp_billboards
      WHERE deleted = 0 
        AND x <> 0 
        AND y <> 0
      GROUP BY r1_id
    ) AS bb1
    ON r.id = bb1.r1_id
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT r2_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM tmp_billboards
      WHERE deleted = 0 
        AND x <> 0 
        AND y <> 0
      GROUP BY r2_id
    ) AS bb2
    ON r.id = bb2.r2_id
ORDER BY r.capital DESC , r.other , r.name ;
```

For efficiency, indexes on `(deleted, r1_id, x, y)` and  `(deleted, r2_id, x, y)` would help to avoid table scans on the `tmp_billboards`.

Answer (score 1):

Add indexes.  The output of `explain` shows you which fields need them.